# changing colour or thickness of one point of data set in ggplot2

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I am currrently plotting the effects of my data set.

I added an extra column (BP) to my dataset and was able to colorise the graph by boat phase.

```
      BoatPhs      fit       se      lower     upper        BP
1         Before 3.685875 0.3287521 3.038621 4.333130     Before
2   After0-20NTA 3.317189 0.6254079 2.085872 4.548506  After0-20
3   After0-20TAA 5.579384 0.5696270 4.457890 6.700878  After0-20
4   After0-20TAP 3.932360 0.4304098 3.084960 4.779760  After0-20
5  After20-40NTA 4.522714 0.7771793 2.992586 6.052842 After20-40
6  After20-40TAA 4.505207 0.5500699 3.422217 5.588196 After20-40
7  After20-40TAP 3.602183 0.3880538 2.838174 4.366192 After20-40
8    ApproachNTA 4.039599 0.5688482 2.919638 5.159560   Approach
9    ApproachTAA 4.421112 0.5176408 3.401969 5.440255   Approach
10   ApproachTAP 4.497809 0.3978328 3.714547 5.281071   Approach
# Speed plot
Spdplot <- ggplot(y, aes(x=BoatPhs, y=fit, colour=BP, ymax=max(fit)*1.05)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5, height = 0), size = 2) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5, height = 0), width = 0.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+

#run Spdplot
Spdplot

#sets x values in results order + relables x + y axes + changes colours
Spdplot + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Before","ApproachNTA","ApproachTAA","ApproachTAP","After0-20NTA","After0-20TAA","After0-20TAP", "After20-40NTA","After20-40TAA","After20-40TAP")) + 
  xlab("Boat Phase") + ylab("Log of Group Travel Speed") + 
  annotate("text", x=6, y=6.2, label="***") +
  annotate("text", x=4, y=4.95, label="*") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5), axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1), axis.text.x = element_text(size=12), axis.text.y = element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#999999","#666666","#CCCCCC","#000000"), 
                      breaks=c("Before", "Approach", "After0-20", "After20-40"),
                      labels=c("Before", "Approach", "After0-20", "After20-40"))
```

What I would like to do is be able to make the point and error bars on the before phase thicker and bolder. Does anyone know how to alter the details of this for a single point? Or multiple different points? I know how to change them for multiple groups but I just would like to make one point stand out a little bit more than the others.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first add another variable to y and make only the before phase T, you can conditionally thicken, bold and color it.  The code below shows color only.

```
y$bold <- c(T, rep(F, 9))
```

Here is the plot done only with red color:

```
Spdplot <- ggplot(y, aes(x=BoatPhs, y=fit, colour=BP, ymax=max(fit)*1.05)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5, height = 0), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se, color = ifelse(y$bold == T, "green", "black")), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5, height = 0),
                width = 0.5) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]